# Are there other ways to increase the chances of getting questions answered besides bounties?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Are there other ways to increase the chances of getting questions answered besides bounties?

For example, I would love to see an answer for this question --[What are the steps to modify a filesystem (say XFS)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307279) -- but I want to earn more reputation points before I start using bounties.

How can I promote certain questions without offering bounties?

Comment: Use the About and Help features of this site  for good pointers and examples!?  Try the Search feature and use the votes filter to get examples of questions and answers that have proven themselves useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a couple of things:

- Share them on social networks with the share buttons.
- Edit the question to improve it.
- Start documenting at least a partial answer to get the question some attention.
- Ask the original poster in a comment to add the results of his research to his question.

  - This is the big one that most people don't do, which is why questions like this languish, I would have expected at least *some* edits to the question with updates by now.